# How to implement Mapping by using Kendo map?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I was trying to add kendo Map, i added necessary css and script files  but i am not getting        `@(Html.Kendo().Map()` i am getting all other widgets like splitter ,slider ,grid but no Map.
What would be the reason any guess?

Added files and dll shown below

```
<link href="~/Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>


@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
```

**EDIT**

It seems Map is not supported in kendo or some .js sequence i am missing or something overriding?

Comment: Did you check http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/troubleshooting are you getting any error in browser console if you just add it?

Comment: @SBirthare i am getting compile time error itself like 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'Map' and no extension method 'Map' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Looks the version you are using does not have the Map. Get the correct version and try.

Comment: which version i can go then?